# How to concatenate strings using Guava?

Tags: java, guava

I wrote some code to concatenate Strings:

```
String inputFile = "";      

for (String inputLine : list) {
    inputFile +=inputLine.trim());
}
```

But I can't use `+` to concatenate, so I decide to go with Guava. So I need to use Joiner.

```
inputFile =joiner.join(inputLine.trim());
```

But it's giving me an error. I need help to fix this. Many Thanks.

Comment: I hate when I get _some error_.

Comment: Why can't you use '+' to concatenate? Also knowing the error is kind of helpful...

Comment: you know that the java String class has a [concat method](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#concat(java.lang.String)), right?

Comment: well my code checker is telling me is not the best way of writing code.

Comment: I need to use Guava. I can't use any other method. that is why i'm stuck here.

Answer (score 22, accepted):

You don't need the loop, you can do the following with Guava:

```
// trim the elements:
List<String> trimmed = Lists.transform(list, new Function<String, String>() {
    @Override
    public String apply(String in) {
        return in.trim();
    }
});
// join them:
String joined = Joiner.on("").join(trimmed);
```

Comment: Faster than me. Deleted my answer and +1 yours. :D

Comment: well how to avoid the spaces,  i use trim() to avoid the spaces.

Comment: @stacktome: you can also do that with Guava, see my updated answer.

Comment: well, I'm going to read a XML file and store it in to a string. that is what  i wanted.

Comment: @stacktome: That is a bad idea. Use an XML parsing library, not a `String`.

Comment: this is already implemented code. so i need to go with string

Comment: @stacktome: then what's wrong with the answer I posted above? Any reason for not accepting it?

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/34459/discussion-between-stacktome-and-jlordo)

Comment: [Guava team weeps](http://code.google.com/p/guava-libraries/wiki/FunctionalExplained). Use the StringBuilder version below. It saves you at least one line of code.

Answer (score 6):

"+" should work. Don't use libraries when you're having problems. Try to understand the nature. Otherrwise  you'll have a very complicated code with hundreds of libraries :))

This should work instead.

```
for (String inputLine : list) {
    inputFile += inputLine.trim();
}
```

And you might also want to use [Stringbuilder](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/java/lang/StringBuilder.html)

```
 StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder("Your string");
 for (String inputLine : list) {
      sb.append(inputLine.trim());
 }
 String inputFile = sb.toString();
```

Comment: It sounded like he was getting code analysis errors when doing the first method do to its inefficiencies.

Comment: well I can't use any other method other than Guava API method.

Comment: StringBuilder is used to concat strings since direct concatenation creates a new object every time.

Comment: Correct is a code analysis error. It suggest me to use Guava. I don't know how to concatenated String using Guava

Comment: What is your code checker? Have you tried using StringBuilder from my answer? It is standard way of doing this

Comment: ya, i use the StringBuilder. it ask me to change.

Answer (score 5):

Try

```
String inputFile = Joiner.on(",").join(list);
```

Comment: here i can't use the trim(). i need to avoid all the spaces in each and every line.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to add the trim, go crazy with the lambdas: 

Try

```
String inputFile = Joiner.on(",")
.join(list.stream()
.map(p->p.trim())
.collect(Collectors.toList()));
```

Comment: Hell no. No need for a `Joiner` here. There's also a [`joining()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/stream/Collectors.html#joining-java.lang.CharSequence-) collector.